# Powermock and Robolectric: issue with android Application class and private method mocking

Tags: android, mocking, powermock, robolectric, powermockito

I am working on tests in a complex Android application, and I am trying to make Robolectric and Powermock work together. I was having strange behaviours, so I tried to break down the problem to isolate it.
I introduced powermock to mock some static and private methods, but I noticed that when I was calling for example

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(valueToReturn).when(classUnderTest, "myPrivateMethod", anyString(), anyInt());
```

the code inside myPrivateMethod was actually executed. Moreover, I was also using Robolectric with a custom Application class, and variables declared inside the custom application class was null during the test execution, even if I double checked that they was properly initialized.

The first attempt I made to see if I was doing something wrong, was to write a very simple class and test it without involving anything else.

The class is this one

```
public class MyClient {

    public boolean publicApi() {
        System.out.println("In publicApi");
        System.out.println("Application.self = " + BaseApplication.self());
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = privateApi("hello", 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail();
        }
        System.out.println("result : " + result);
        return result == 20;
    }

    private int privateApi(String whatever, int num) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In privateAPI");
        thirdPartyCall();
        int resp = 10;
        return resp;
    }

    private void thirdPartyCall() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In thirdPartyCall");
        //Actual WS call which may be down while running the test cases
    }
}
```

And this is the test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClient.class)
public class MyClientTest1 {

    @Test
    public void testPublicAPI() throws Exception {
        MyClient classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClient());

        PowerMockito.doReturn(20).when(classUnderTest, "privateApi", anyString(), anyInt());

        boolean result = classUnderTest.publicApi();
        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

In this case I have the expected result, and the output is

```
In publicApi
Application.self = null
result : 20
```

Then I tried to introduce robolectric. The application class is this one

```
public class MyTestApplication
    extends BaseApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

Where BaseApplication is this

```
/**
 * Real application class
 */
public class BaseApplication
    extends Application {
    protected static BaseApplication sSelf;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("filling Application.self");
        sSelf = this;
    }

    public static BaseApplication self() {
        return sSelf;
    }
}
```

And this is the test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, application = MyTestApplication.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClient.class)
public class MyClientTest2 {

    @Test
    public void testPublicAPI() throws Exception {
        MyClient classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClient());

        PowerMockito.doReturn(20).when(classUnderTest, "privateApi", anyString(), anyInt());

        boolean result = classUnderTest.publicApi();

        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
filling Application.self
In privateAPI
In thirdPartyCall

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at com.myapp.MyClientTest2.testPublicAPI(MyClientTest2.java:31)
-> at com.myapp.MyClientTest2.testPublicAPI(MyClientTest2.java:31)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

As you can see here the first strangeness: the private method is executed when I call

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(20).when(classUnderTest, "privateApi", anyString(), anyInt());
```

and the same call (line 31 is exactly that one) throws that exception

Then I made another attempt to integrate Robolectric and Powermock in the other suggested way in the docs, using PowerMockRule

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, application = MyTestApplication.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClient.class)
public class MyClientTest3 {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void testPublicAPI() throws Exception {
        MyClient classUnderTest = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClient());

        PowerMockito.doReturn(20).when(classUnderTest, "privateApi", anyString(), anyInt());

        boolean result = classUnderTest.publicApi();

        Assert.assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
filling Application.self
In publicApi
Application.self = null
result : 20
```

Here the exception is gone, the private method is successfully mocked, but another problem comes in: MyTestApplication.self() returns null when accessed, even if the log `filling Application.self` indicates that the `sSelf` variable is valorized (I also checked it in the debugger)

This last solution seems to be the best one, but the problem it causes makes it impossible to use for me because I use Application.self() to access many dagger related stuff.

How should it be possible that the `sSelf` field is null at that point?

Many thanks for any help